# Exporting actual responses rather than just question response IDs when exporting response data from qualtrics

Tags: python, qualtrics

I'm currently trying to export qualtrics survey response data following the [basic guide](https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/getting-survey-responses-via-the-new-export-apis). I am using Python to do this, and have it set up to function properly.

However, when exporting the records are not populated by the actual response text but rather the response ID associated with that response in qualtrics.

Example you have these responses to a question:
1. January
2. May
3. July

If three people respond, I'm instead getting 3, 1, 2 in the records rather than July, January, May which is what I want to receive.

I can't seem to find a reference to this on the API directly is anyone aware if there is functionality built into the API by default to do this sort of thing? I could obviously just create a map and map each response but that would be the cumbersome amount of manual work and not dynamic so I'm trying to find alternative options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameter useLabels to get labels instead of recodes.

Otherwise, you could use either List Questions (https://api.qualtrics.com/reference#list-questions-1) or Get Survey (https://api.qualtrics.com/reference#get-survey) to get a map to look up the choice text.